# Scala way to construct code of operations and types

Tags: scala

I have the following operations: `OpSUM`, `OpAVG`, `OpSTD`, ... which I would like to implement for `Int`, `Float`, `String` and additional types.

The brute force way might be something like this:

```
trait Operation

case class OpSUM[T: TypeTag]() extends Operation {
    typeOf[T] match {
        case t if t =:= typeOf[String] => Do some string work
        case t if t <:< typeOf[Int] => Do some Int work
        ...
    }
}
case class OpAVG[T: TypeTag]() extends Operation {
    typeOf[T] match {
        case t if t =:= typeOf[String] => Do some string work
        case t if t <:< typeOf[Int] => Do some Int work
        ...
    }
}
...
```

Is there a better scala way to do this?
The main problem I see here is that Op and the type are coupled, meaning for each operation the type does different work.

Comment: Scala typeclasses might be something to check out. This article is a pretty good introduction: https://blog.scalac.io/2017/04/19/typeclasses-in-scala.html

Comment: I started looking in that direction, but the coupling between the two classes got me a bit stuck

Answer (score 2):

If you try approach with type classes (as @mrmcgreg proposed in his comment) this can look like:

```
  trait OpSUM[T] {
    def doSomeWork
  }
  object OpSUM {
    implicit val stringCase: OpSUM[String] = new OpSUM[String] {
      override def doSomeWork = ???
    }

    implicit def intCase[T <: Int]: OpSUM[T] = new OpSUM[T] {
      override def doSomeWork = ???
    }
  }

  trait OpAVG[T] {
    def doSomeOtherWork
  }
  object OpAVG {
    implicit val stringCase: OpAVG[String] = new OpAVG[String] {
      override def doSomeOtherWork = ???
    }
    implicit def intCase[T <: Int]: OpAVG[T] = new OpAVG[T] {
      override def doSomeOtherWork = ???
    }
  }

// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I link also [this explanation of Type Classes](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2013/02/06/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-12-type-classes.html) by Daniel Westheide since the application domain he uses for his post looks similar to yours.